# Google Drive API Integrate on PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I was wondering if you have any thoughts on how to implement a website that can upload a file that would save on the google drive using PHP. I'm currently using this link https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client, but it gives me an error I'm not sure what did I do these are my codes:

```
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setAuthConfig($oauth_credentials);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);


$client->setClientId('sample.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('_WwlE1Q0Nm_qkvOCLEtciRbj');

// add "?logout" to the URL to remove a token from the session
if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
}

/************************************************
 * If we have a code back from the OAuth 2.0 flow,
 * we need to exchange that with the
 * Google_Client::fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode()
 * function. We store the resultant access token
 * bundle in the session, and redirect to ourself.
 ************************************************/
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
  $client->setAccessToken($token);

  // store in the session also
  $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $token;

  // redirect back to the example
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

I'm not sure what I can  upload.

Comment: What is your actual question? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve how to ask questions

Comment: my apologies , i was wondering if how to use the google api drive in php i'm not sure how to use its there documentation is very confusing

Comment: What you are trying to do is confusing and complicated.   The code you have there is just the start really.  Here are a few more things for you to digest https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/simple-file-upload.php https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php

Comment: Hi @DaImTo i have implemented here i'm not sure what to do next to upload https://qsnapnet.com/snaps/0k4d1pqhua98uxr

Comment: wow @DaImTo i have checked your profile wow your a Google API experts so cool ,  i wish i was like you though T_T

Comment: tinyurl.com/myuploadhere @dalmto you can see it here sorry